# Polymer Iron Flex Layout Classes Not Working

Tags: flexbox, polymer-1.0

I was trying to use iron-flex-layout during the development of a website and became extremely frustrated when I spent hours try to get it to work, but to no avail. Eventually, I decided to try a bare-bones web page to see if it would work (thinking that it was probably something in my website). However, I tried the following code and I still can't get it to work! Can anyone spot my errors?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
        <style>
            body {
                font-weight: 300;
            }
            div {
                border: 2px solid grey;
                background-color: white;
            }
            .layout {
              margin-bottom: 20px;
              background-color: grey;
            }
            p {
              margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body fullbleed unresolved>
        <div class="horizontal layout">
            <div><p>div</p></div>
            <div class="flex"><p>flex (horizontal layout)</p></div>
            <div><p>div</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Here is what the result is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2A9i.png)

[And here is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXgFP.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the CSS classes, you need to import them separately:

`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">`

The import you have only gives you access to the `@apply` mixins. Do note that Polymer is dropping `/deep/` support in their elements and are encouraging people to use the mixins instead of the classes: https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/12/01/deprecating-deep/

Comment: That isn't correct.  Exerpt: "Currently, the layout class stylesheet uses the /deep/ combinator and therefore, works across all local DOM boundaries.

Because /deep/ is slated to be removed from the shadow DOM spec, this stylesheet will eventually be replaced by a set of rules that do not use /deep/. When that happens, the stylesheet will need to be imported into each scope where it's used." from https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout.  Looks like they will replace the use of deep with something else.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect!

Comment: in iron-flex-layout there is no folder called classes

Comment: @Marcus, Can we use the import link inside a polymer element? Here is my quesion for reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/46826321/6191987](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46826321/6191987)