# Polymer 2.0 custom style property is not working under dom-module

Tags: html, css, polymer-2.x

I have upgraded polymer project to 2.0 version. After that some css class is missing from div.

There is a link to **iron-flex-layout.html** from **my-home.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
```

And in **my-home.html** page have some styles like following:

```
<dom-module id="my-home">
<template>
<style is="custom-style">
.flex-vertical {
  @apply --layout-vertical;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flexchild-vertical {
  @apply --layout-flex;
  @apply --layout-horizontal;
}
</style>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

These styles are calling from **iron-flex-layout.html**

```
--layout-vertical
--layout-flex
--layout-horizontal
```

But its not loading into my output. Here is the screenshots from my browser:

**Old version:**

[image]

**Upgraded version:**

[image]

I think the problem may because of that there is a `#shadow-root` generated.

Can I change style links / html links or any other in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Got the answer from here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#class-based-elements-import-the-css-mixin-shim

It is the version problem with the `iron-flex-layout`. I just updated it and everything is fine now.

The latest version (2.0) have a `<custom-style>` object wrapping whole the styles inside `iron-flex-layout.html`

Here is the latest version: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout